# Value errors (invalid literal and truth value ambigous) in a data frame IF statement

Tags: python

Tried looking at similar question ([ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48481223/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-a-dataframe-is-ambiguous)) but the answer went well over my head, I am asking in the context of an IF statement that isn't working and there's a problem converting a string to a number in mine

I'm trying to run a validation on a row of a data table. The criteria is to find the row where `type` equals 'employees-full-time' and `value` (which is string which I need converted to a number value) is greater than or equal to `min_value`.

I cannot get it to work. Here are the details of my problem and the errors:

**Dataframe data types**

```
category       object
type           object
value          object
value_type     object
mandatory        bool
min_value     float64
```

**Script**

```
# validate full time employees value
if df.loc[(df['type'] == 'employees-full-time') & (df['value'].astype(int) >= df['min_value'])]:
    print('full time employees cool')
else:
    print('full time employees not so cool')
```

**Errors**

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'true'
```

If I reduce the script to exclude the second criteria, it complains about:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Duplicate: [ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48481223/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-a-dataframe-is-ambiguous)

Comment: @esqew I tried that one, but I don't get it at all

Comment: 'true' can't be converted to `int`, because it isn't an integer. The boolean `True`, can be converted to an integer (0 or 1) because booleans are binary, but not a string. So check your data to be sure it makes sense for what you are trying to do. The second error is because you are asking `if ...` and supplying a data frame as output. There is no row-wise operation output like I think you are expecting, it does not take each row and run it through the `if`.  You can either create a new column to find which ones are true, or if the condition is if any are true, use `df.any()`, same for all

Comment: @fam-woodpecker thanks for help, the `df['value']` is a number stored in a string object. "6" but the `min_value` is a float. I am trying to find row where `type` == employees-full-time and take the string value of 6 treated as a number to make sure the number submitted is greater than or equal to `min_value`. The result I want is a true or false on the condition

Comment: when I create a column for the test `df['test'] = np.where(df['type'] == 'employees-full-time') & (df['value'] == '6')` is works fine but only because I compared a string object with a string value hard coded as "6". I need `value` in this case to be treated as a float and compared with another value in the same row which is already a float

Comment: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'true'` implies that the string `'true'`  is being converted to an integer, hence the error, I meant to suggest that you should check to make sure that there are no `'true'`s in the columns.

Comment: @fam-woodpecker ah, I see. In my model, value is of any type hence comes in from JSON as a string. The type and category of an object in an array informs the validation of that value. so yeah, `0    true, 1     6`. In my IF statement, I tried to select the correct object in array first, then treat it as an individual

Comment: Tried this and getting the  "The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous" error again `employee_full_time = df.loc[df['type'] == 'employees-full-time'].copy()
if employee_full_time[employee_full_time['value'].astype(float) >= employee_full_time['min_value']]:
    print('passed')`

Comment: Yes, that would work if that separates the `'value'` to be only strings convertible to integers

Answer (score 0):

I had to isolate the data frame record before I could validate it based upon the parameters in the row. I am concerned however that, since the origin is bsed on a dynamic set of values, it could exponentially grow. How many data frames are going to be ok without impacting performance? I'm thinking like, maybe 300 dynamic objects in an array which would end up in their own data frame.
The way I wanted to avoid this was row by row validation of the data frame so, maybe a for loop is better?

```
# validate full time employees value
employee_full_time = df.loc[df['type'] == 'employees-full-time'].copy()
if (employee_full_time['value'].astype(float) < 
employee_full_time['min_value']).all():
    print('Invalid employee full time value')
else:
    print('Value of Full time employees is valid')
```